# Non-beta site design feedback

Tags: discussion, design

I realize (now) that the site design was a community process, and this feedback may not be desired or appropriate, but, well, here it is.  Vote to close if and as necessary...

I find myself not participating in Android Enthusiasts simply because of the new theme.  It's been a couple of weeks now and instead of going away my feeling are intensifying.  I almost don't know how to put what I don't like about the design into words, but I realize I have to at least try.  The whole design is too...light?  Bright?  Monotonous/monolithic?  All of which combines to create an almost literal blur.  The beta design had non-subtle (but still non-obtrusive) color, the questions were easily distinguishable, questions with tags I like were well-highlighted.  Different elements had texture or edges or were otherwise easily distinguishable from the background.  The new theme is just too...subtle?  All-encompassing?  Overwhelming?

I open the site each day (via the Firefox Morning Coffee extension), and have participated daily since I joined 6 months ago.  The last two weeks...more often than not, I simply close the window.  I hope I'm the only one feeling this, but in case I'm not, I felt I should post it.

I know how much work a cohesive site design involves, and I in no way wish to denigrate the work that went into this site design.  Tastes and styles are highly subjective things, and I don't expect to be liking everything I see on this great net of ours.  The result of this design though is almost physically pushing me away and I just wanted to give feedback in case others were feeling anything similar.

Thanks for listening!

Comment: I don't know of anyone else who dislikes the new design.  Check out the comments on http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/417/new-design-launched

Comment: I'm sorry you don't like the new design. You are, of course, entitled to your opinion. It really keeps you from participating? Anyway, there are a number of ways you can impose your own style sheets on the site. You could probably revert it back to the beta look-and-feel if you wanted to. Or just make it less "bright".

Comment: That's what I plan on doing, Al...

Comment: Not the entire design, but certain parts could do with some contrast work to make them stand out. Also, a wider, fluid layout would ensure monitors with multiple resolution widths can comfortably see the site.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! By all means, please specify in detail which elements you think need to be improved. I normally fix usability issues right away. However, please keep in mind that I rarely make changes based on subjective personal preferences.

Comment: I find the buttons and badges hard to read. I think it's a combination of low-constrast grays, plus detail -- gradients, shading, circles and cirlces. SO-mothership has simple triangles. Obvious and readable!

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in [MinimalOverflow](https://stackapps.com/questions/2143/minimaloverflow-a-themescript-for-stackexchange), a userscript that essentially unthemes any SE site. Here's what it looks like applied to this site:

[Screenshot of MinimalOverflow applied to Android http://so.mrozekma.com/android-minimal.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/android-minimal.png)

Answer (score 2):

Is the complaint simply that the site is too monochrome?

I guess I could see that.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the current design is the most beautiful among many SE sites. It's prettier than SO, PSE, PMSE, and English Language. I like the header and the background and I think the border around the client area is nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

I *really* like the design - very clean & elegant.

It does occasionally feel a little bit washed out / monochrome however. I'm sure there are specific elements that could be a bit darker or more colourful without changing the overall elegant feel.

**I think the most constructive thing to do would be to try and identify specific elements like this**, as GAThrawn did [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/483/post-question-buttons-look-disabled). A few more little accents and highlights like this and I'm sure it would all click together beautifully!